# Making a logger available for use with a JSON struct

Tags: go, logging, struct, go-zap

I have a JSON struct that looks something like this in `pkg/response/foobar.go`

```
type Foo struct {
    RequestID      string                     `json:"request_id"`
    Response       string                     `json:"response"`
}

func (resp *Foo) JSONBytes() []byte {
    result, err := json.Marshal(resp)
    if err != nil {
        // log the error (see below)
    }
    return result
}
```

I am *very* new to Go, and I am trying to integrate Uber's Zap logger. In `pkg/endpoint/route1.go`, I have

```
func processRequest(s *zap.SugaredLogger, // other params) error {
    for resp := range responses {
        //... other cases

        case *response.Foo:
            resp.Sugar = s // want to do something like this
            respBytes := resp.JSONBytes()
            wsResponses <- respBytes
    }
}
```

I then want to be able to pass the logger that's being used in `processRequest` and make it available to use for `JSONBytes()`. However, I am not sure of the implications of mixing a JSON struct with methods:

```
type Foo struct {
    RequestID      string                     `json:"request_id"`
    Response       string                     `json:"response"`
    Sugar          *zap.SugaredLogger         `json:"-"`
}
```

where I can then use the logger in `JSONBytes()`. If I try passing it as an argument in to `JSONBytes(s)`, I get

```
resp (variable of type response.Response) cannot have dynamic type *response.Foo (wrong type for method JSONBytes (have func(s *go.uber.org/zap.SugaredLogger) []byte, want func() []byte))compilerImpossibleAssert
```

What is the most idiomatic way to make the logger available for `JSONBytes()`.

Comment: (1) The call to json.Marshal will not fail unless you add fields that cannot be marshaled.      Writing to a default logger may be good enough for handling the error (2) It looks like the caller, `processRequest`, handles errors.  Another option is to return the error to the caller. (3) The error message is telling you that the type switch case is impossible:  the type *resposne.Foo does not statisfy the response.Response interface.

Comment: setting the logger on the data model struct is... quite uncommon. you should return `([]byte, error)` from `JSONBytes` and log at the call site. Also the JSON tag should be `json:"-"` (with quotes)

Comment: I ended up going with Penelope's second choice